# Error: r.walk GRASS function in QGIS (Mac)

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, error, mac

I've been trying to run the r.walk GRASS function in QGIS on my Mac, but got several error messages (unable to open datasource, raster map not found). I used two different DEMs just to be sure, but the error messages keep repeating – so, I guess, it's a problem with my system? As you've probably guessed by now, I am more or less a complete novice and would be very glad to get some help.

Down below the full report:

```
QGIS-Version: 3.30.2-'s-Hertogenbosch
QGIS-Codeversion: 0992b53397
Qt-Version: 5.15.2
Python-Version: 3.9.5
GDAL-Version: 3.3.2
GEOS-Version: 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
PROJ-Version: Rel. 8.1.1, September 1st, 2021
PDAL-Version: 2.3.0 (git-version: Release)
Algorithmus gestartet um: 2023-08-01T16:04:03
Algorithmus r.walk.points startet…
Eingabeparameter:
{ '-k' : False, '-n' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '', 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'elevation' : '/Desktop/Ziegel/GIS/eu_dem_v11_E50N10/Südgriechenland.tif', 'friction' : '%3Fcrs%3DEPSG%3A3035%26extent%3D5205825%2C1539250%2C5657825%2C1854600%26width%3D18080%26height%3D12614%26formula%3D0', 'lambda' : 1, 'max_cost' : 0, 'memory' : 300, 'null_cost' : None, 'outdir' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'slope_factor' : -0.2125, 'start_points' : '/Desktop/Ziegel/GIS/Olympia.shp', 'stop_points' : None, 'walk_coeff' : '0.72,6.0,1.9998,-1.9998' }

g.proj -c wkt="/private/var/folders/k8/yy52dstn4pgb1y5c0cbntx800000gn/T/processing_FxsyWM/66407c75de684aeda0f5f43e3281831a/crs.prj"
r.in.gdal input="/Desktop/Ziegel/GIS/eu_dem_v11_E50N10/Südgriechenland.tif" band=1 output="rast_64c910d31792d41" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="%3Fcrs%3DEPSG%3A3035%26extent%3D5205825%2C1539250%2C5657825%2C1854600%26width%3D18080%26height%3D12614%26formula%3D0" band=1 output="rast_64c910d317a0842" --overwrite -o
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="/Desktop/Ziegel/GIS/Olympia.shp" output="vector_64c910d317e8e43" --overwrite -o
g.region n=1854600.0 s=1539250.0 e=5657825.0 w=5205825.0 res=25.0
r.walk elevation=rast_64c910d31792d41 friction=rast_64c910d317a0842 start_points=vector_64c910d317e8e43 walk_coeff="0.72,6.0,1.9998,-1.9998" lambda=1 slope_factor=-0.2125 max_cost=0 memory=300 output=output265787f574dc4af8822d09cc0bf5599a outdir=outdir265787f574dc4af8822d09cc0bf5599a --overwrite
g.region raster=output265787f574dc4af8822d09cc0bf5599a
r.out.gdal -t -m input="output265787f574dc4af8822d09cc0bf5599a" output="/private/var/folders/k8/yy52dstn4pgb1y5c0cbntx800000gn/T/processing_FxsyWM/c6fbf27e7332480bac505cd1bffdf029/output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=outdir265787f574dc4af8822d09cc0bf5599a
r.out.gdal -t -m input="outdir265787f574dc4af8822d09cc0bf5599a" output="/private/var/folders/k8/yy52dstn4pgb1y5c0cbntx800000gn/T/processing_FxsyWM/14c4e432fbb94eb685f97cf279c2351c/outdir.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
Default locale settings are missing. GRASS running with C locale.
Starting GRASS GIS...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing </private/var/folders/k8/yy52dstn4pgb1y5c0cbntx800000gn/T/processing_FxsyWM/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> ...
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
Over-riding projection check
Importing raster map <rast_64c910d31792d41>...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
ERROR: Unable to open datasource <%3Fcrs%3DEPSG%3A3035%26extent%3D5205825%2C1539250%2C5657825%2C1854600%26width%3D18080%26height%3D12614%26formula%3D0>
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <Olympia> contains polygons...
0..100
Creating attribute table for layer <Olympia>...
Importing 1 features (OGR layer <Olympia>)...
0..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Building topology for vector map <vector_64c910d317e8e43@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
Walking costs are a=0.72 b=6 c=1.9998 d=-1.9998
Lambda is 1
Slope_factor is -0.2125
ERROR: Raster map <rast_64c910d317a0842> not found
ERROR: Raster map <output265787f574dc4af8822d09cc0bf5599a> not found
ERROR: Raster map or group <output265787f574dc4af8822d09cc0bf5599a> not found
ERROR: Raster map <outdir265787f574dc4af8822d09cc0bf5599a> not found
ERROR: Raster map or group <outdir265787f574dc4af8822d09cc0bf5599a> not found
Execution of </private/var/folders/k8/yy52dstn4pgb1y5c0cbntx800000gn/T/processing_FxsyWM/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Default locale settings are missing. GRASS running with C locale.
Starting GRASS GIS...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing </private/var/folders/k8/yy52dstn4pgb1y5c0cbntx800000gn/T/processing_FxsyWM/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> ...
ERROR: Raster map <output265787f574dc4af8822d09cc0bf5599a> not found
ERROR: Raster map or group <output265787f574dc4af8822d09cc0bf5599a> not found
ERROR: Raster map <outdir265787f574dc4af8822d09cc0bf5599a> not found
ERROR: Raster map or group <outdir265787f574dc4af8822d09cc0bf5599a> not found
Execution of </private/var/folders/k8/yy52dstn4pgb1y5c0cbntx800000gn/T/processing_FxsyWM/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Execution completed in 12.36 Sekunden
Ergebnisse:
{'outdir': '/private/var/folders/k8/yy52dstn4pgb1y5c0cbntx800000gn/T/processing_FxsyWM/14c4e432fbb94eb685f97cf279c2351c/outdir.tif',
'output': '/private/var/folders/k8/yy52dstn4pgb1y5c0cbntx800000gn/T/processing_FxsyWM/c6fbf27e7332480bac505cd1bffdf029/output.tif'}

Lade Ergebnis Layer
Die folgenden Layer wurden nicht erzeugt.
• /private/var/folders/k8/yy52dstn4pgb1y5c0cbntx800000gn/T/processing_FxsyWM/14c4e432fbb94eb685f97cf279c2351c/outdir.tif
• /private/var/folders/k8/yy52dstn4pgb1y5c0cbntx800000gn/T/processing_FxsyWM/c6fbf27e7332480bac505cd1bffdf029/output.tif
Im 'Protokoll-Fenster' im QGIS-Hauptfenster sind mehr Informationen zur Ausführung des Algorithmus zu finden.
```